# Определить знак зодиака prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Как я понял мне надо задать правила типо:

```
знак(овен,21,март).
знак(овен,22,март).
знак(овен,23,март).
знак(овен,24,март).
знак(овен,25,март).
знак(овен,26,март).
знак(овен,27,март).
знак(овен,28,март).
знак(овен,29,март).
знак(овен,30,март).
знак(овен,31,март).
знак(овен,between(1,20),апрель).
```

как правильно использовать between, чтобы не перебирать по числу все значения?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сократить программу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821388/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83)

Comment: Нет, тот вопрос дубликат этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Определить знак зодиака

**Решение:**

```
    % zodiac_sign/5
    % 12 фактов
     zodiac_sign( водолей, 20, январь, 18, февраль ).
     zodiac_sign( рыбы, 19, февраль, 20, март ).
     zodiac_sign( овен, 21, март, 20, апрель ).
     %....

    % month/3
    % 13 фактов (+1 для февраля)
     month(1, январь, 31).
     month(2, февраль, 28).
     month(3, февраль, 29).
     month(4,  март, 31).
    % ...

    leap_year( 1980).

    leap_year(Y)  :-
        nonvar(Y),
        leap_year(Yp),
        nonvar(Yp),
        Y is Yp + 4
        ;
        Yp is Y + 4.


    start:-
        write('Введите дату рождения...'),
        askfor( 'число', Day ),
        askfor( 'месяц', Month ),
        askfor('год', Year ),
        check_leap(Year),
        zodiac_sign( Zodiac, Day1, Month1, Day2, Month2 ),
        max_year_day_at( Month1, Max1 ),
        max_year_day_at( Month2, Max2 ),
        max_year_day_at( Month, Max ),
        between( Max1, Max2, Max ), nl,
        write('Ваш знак зодиака:'),
        write( Zodiac ), nl.

    askfor( Prompt, Response ):-
        write( Prompt ),
        read( Response ).

     check_leap(Year):-
         cleanup,
           leap_year(Year) ->
           assertz('$correction'(1))
          ;
          assertz('$correction'(0))).


   % макс день года в месяце (напр в деквбре = 365(366) в январе = 31)
   max_year_day_at( Month, N ):-
        month( _ , Month, Days), _ анонимная переменна я**EDIT**
         Month == 'февраль' -> 
          '$correction'(Corr); Corr = 0,
        next_month( Month, NextMonth ),
        max_year_day_at( NextMonth, MaxDaySoFar ),
        N is MaxDaySoFar + Days + Corr.


    next_month(Month, Next):-
        month(Index, Name, _),
        Index == 12 ->
            Index1 = 1
            ;
            Index1 = Index + 1,
        month(Index1, Next, _ ).

cleanup :-
    retract('$correction'(_)), false; true.

 %----------------------------------------
```

**ИНФОРМАЦИЯ**

[Power of Prolog, Markus Triska](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/)
  [Power of Prolog, глава, посвящённая *CSP over Finite Domains* (**clpfd**), Markus Triska](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpfd)
Используйте декларативную арифметику **clpfd**.

[SWI-Prolog `between/3` doc](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)

Comment: не получается через бетвин.Я ввожу цифру в этом диапазоне и оно выдает false

Comment: вот я задал 2 факта вышеуказанных.
спрашиваю:
знак(X,5,апрель).
ответ- false.Хотя должен же выдать:X=овен.

Comment: Понятно, что не получается, в Прологе нет вложенных вызовов функций. p(f(X)) - f(X) это данные,  составной терм (compound, кстати в Прологе они назывются функциями, а процедуры предикатами). Чтобы моделировть вложенные функции надо добавлять доп. аргумент в кот . будет возвращаться "значение": p(f(X,Return)).

Comment: `zodiac_sign(Zodiac, Day1, Month1, Day2, Month2)` тут мне надо указать даты зодиаков?  типо `zodiac_sign(овен, 21, март, 20, апрель)`

`day_of_year(Day1, Month1, Year, DY1)` вот тут что такое `DY1` ?

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, написать для овна пример.А то чего-то не понимаю некоторые моменты.Зачем тут год вообще нужен?

Comment: `askfor` это что?ругается на него - undefined procedure.
`zodiac_sign(овен,21, март, 20, апрель)` - вот так мне надо перечислить все знаки?
`day_of_year(21, март, Year, DY1) ` так перечислять начальные даты или что?

Comment: мне знаки перечислять в start? или перед ним?и вы убрали `zodiac_sign`?

Comment: ничего не получается, но спасибо и на этом.

Comment: всё получается я переделал много  если вас устроит ответ на 100% можете upvote за него )

Comment: @Anton Решение готово (правда не тестировал)

Comment: большое спасибо.

Comment: я всё же не пойму.Мы вводим тут 3 переменные `day`,`month`,`year`.
Далее в расчетах нужные `month1`,`day1`.Откуда они берутся не могу понять?

Comment: переменные явно не декларируются они вводятся кодером там где нужны

Comment: ну вот смотрите, я ввожу в `start` 3 переменные `day`,`month`,`year`.Что оно должно вставить в `zodiac_sign( Zodiac, Day1, Month1, Day2, Month2 )`?Оно же просто не сработает, или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: при вызове `zodiac_sign/5`  сначала вызвается первый факт  ` zodiac_sign( водолей, 20, январь, 18, февраль ).` он спешно унифицируется с целью  zodiac_sign( Zodiac, Day1, Month1, Day2, Month2), те все переменные получают значения соотвествено